# Increase Query Overall performance

Tags: mysql, database, join, indexing

I am struggling to improve my query's overall performance since I am no pro when it comes to writing queries or optimizing it via indexes. Either way, consider my SQL Fiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fc5fd2/2/0) for an exact sample. I am looking for a way (if there is any) to use indexes in executing the query for faster execution (the data as of now is small, but it will eventually grow and the query will run slow - which is what i fear).

Below is my current `EXPLAIN` result:
[image]

Further information below, which contains the whole schema and query:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `battery_batch`;
CREATE TABLE `battery_batch`  (
  `bb_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cc_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `batch_num` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_encoded` datetime(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `encoded_by_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`bb_id`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `batch_num`(`batch_num`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `cc_id`(`cc_id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 2 CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci ROW_FORMAT = Dynamic;

INSERT INTO `battery_batch` VALUES (1, 5, 1, '2018-04-12 09:35:37', 1);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `battery_inbound_shipment`;
CREATE TABLE `battery_inbound_shipment`  (
  `bis_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bb_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `bpn_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `order_num` varchar(25) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `shipment_id` varchar(25) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `encoded_by_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_encoded` datetime(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`bis_id`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `bb_id`(`bb_id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 4 CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci ROW_FORMAT = Dynamic;

INSERT INTO `battery_inbound_shipment` VALUES (1, 1, 1, 'RTS1', 'SID1', 1, '2018-04-14 18:48:48');
INSERT INTO `battery_inbound_shipment` VALUES (2, 1, 2, 'RTS1', 'SID1', 1, '2018-04-14 18:48:50');
INSERT INTO `battery_inbound_shipment` VALUES (3, 1, 3, 'RTS2', 'SID1', 1, '2018-04-14 18:48:53');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `battery_part_num`;
CREATE TABLE `battery_part_num`  (
  `bpn_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mb_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `part_num` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `part_desc` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `encoded_by_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_encoded` datetime(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`bpn_id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 4 CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci ROW_FORMAT = Dynamic;

INSERT INTO `battery_part_num` VALUES (1, 71, '6424B', 'NEW PRODUCT', 1, '2018-04-14 18:48:48');
INSERT INTO `battery_part_num` VALUES (2, 51, '6422B', 'NEW PRODUCT', 1, '2018-04-14 18:48:50');
INSERT INTO `battery_part_num` VALUES (3, 71, '6423B', 'NEW PRODUCT', 1, '2018-04-14 18:48:52');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `battery_record`;
CREATE TABLE `battery_record`  (
  `br_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bis_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `battery_serial` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `date_encoded` datetime(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `encoded_by_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `battery_origin` enum('A Battery','B Battery') CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'A Battery',
  `void_record_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`br_id`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `battery_serial`(`battery_serial`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `battery_serial_search`(`battery_serial`, `void_record_id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 64522 CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci ROW_FORMAT = Dynamic;

INSERT INTO `battery_record` VALUES (2, 1, 'ABC74661V8J1234CV', '2018-04-14 18:48:48', 1, 'A Battery', 367113);
INSERT INTO `battery_record` VALUES (4, 1, 'ABC747307ER1234CV', '2018-04-14 18:48:48', 1, 'A Battery', 367113);
INSERT INTO `battery_record` VALUES (6, 1, 'ABC802714SQ1234C6', '2018-04-14 18:48:48', 1, 'A Battery', 367113);
INSERT INTO `battery_record` VALUES (8, 1, 'ABC802714SS1234C4', '2018-04-14 18:48:48', 1, 'A Battery', 367113);
INSERT INTO `battery_record` VALUES (10, 1, 'ABC80270F6H1234CX', '2018-04-14 18:48:48', 1, 'A Battery', 367113);
INSERT INTO `battery_record` VALUES (11, 1, 'ABC802714SU1234C2', '2018-04-14 18:48:48', 1, 'A Battery', 367113);
INSERT INTO `battery_record` VALUES (12, 1, 'ABC802714SN1234C8', '2018-04-14 18:48:48', 1, 'A Battery', 367113);
INSERT INTO `battery_record` VALUES (13, 1, 'ABC80270PPM1234C2', '2018-04-14 18:48:48', 1, 'A Battery', 367113);
INSERT INTO `battery_record` VALUES (14, 1, 'ABC80270PPH1234C6', '2018-04-14 18:48:48', 1, 'A Battery', 367113);
INSERT INTO `battery_record` VALUES (15, 1, 'ABC80270QZT1234CZ', '2018-04-14 18:48:48', 1, 'A Battery', 367113);
INSERT INTO `battery_record` VALUES (16, 1, 'ABC80270V191234C6', '2018-04-14 18:48:48', 1, 'A Battery', 367113);
INSERT INTO `battery_record` VALUES (17, 1, 'ABC80270V1M1234CU', '2018-04-14 18:48:48', 1, 'A Battery', 367113);
INSERT INTO `battery_record` VALUES (18, 1, 'ABC80270EN71234CU', '2018-04-14 18:48:48', 1, 'A Battery', 367113);
INSERT INTO `battery_record` VALUES (19, 1, 'ABC80270V1D1234C2', '2018-04-14 18:48:48', 1, 'A Battery', 367113);
INSERT INTO `battery_record` VALUES (20, 1, 'ABC80270F3J1234C5', '2018-04-14 18:48:48', 1, 'A Battery', 367113);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `battery_verified_record`;
CREATE TABLE `battery_verified_record`  (
  `bvr_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `br_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `u_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `scan_date` datetime(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`bvr_id`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `br_id`(`br_id`) USING BTREE,
  UNIQUE INDEX `scan_date`(`scan_date`, `br_id`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `u_id`(`u_id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 6 CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci ROW_FORMAT = Dynamic;

INSERT INTO `battery_verified_record` VALUES (1, 2, 1, '2018-04-15 11:20:09');
INSERT INTO `battery_verified_record` VALUES (2, 4, 1, '2018-04-15 11:54:00');
INSERT INTO `battery_verified_record` VALUES (3, 6, 1, '2018-04-15 12:23:55');
INSERT INTO `battery_verified_record` VALUES (4, 8, 1, '2018-04-15 12:23:57');
INSERT INTO `battery_verified_record` VALUES (5, 10, 1, '2018-04-15 12:23:58');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `user`;
CREATE TABLE `user`  (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Username` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `Password` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `PasswordExpirationDate` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `FirstName` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `LastName` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `LocationId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `IsActive` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `IsDeleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `UserTypeId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `VendorId` int(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `ResetPassword` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `Workerid` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `ComputerProcessMappingId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `LastName`(`LastName`, `FirstName`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 489 CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci ROW_FORMAT = Dynamic;

INSERT INTO `user` VALUES (1, 'superadmin', '1000:Q8v+4nGsGUGvmvlCkhdWI0Sf+ABCDEFG+YY:vHkHPWNrvLyX5pUm8Q4HrmJlTkZhpvZL', '2017-02-07 09:41:04.000000', 'Super', 'Admin', 4, 1, 0, 1, NULL, 0, '1', 0);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `customer_client`;
CREATE TABLE `customer_client`  (
  `cc_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `client_code` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `client_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NOT AVAILABLE',
  `date_encoded` datetime(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cc_id`) USING BTREE,
  UNIQUE INDEX `tmp_1`(`client_code`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 85 CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci ROW_FORMAT = Dynamic;

INSERT INTO `customer_client` VALUES (5, 'MNO - 05', 'NOT AVAILABLE', '2018-03-26 14:28:22');





####


SELECT
    br.battery_serial 'BatterySerial',
    cc.client_code 'Client',
    bb.batch_num 'Batch',
    CONCAT(u.LastName, ', ', u.FirstName) 'VerifiedBy',
    bvr.scan_date 'ScanDate'
FROM
    battery_verified_record bvr
JOIN
    battery_record br
ON
    br.br_id = bvr.br_id
JOIN
    battery_inbound_shipment bis
ON
    bis.bis_id = br.bis_id
JOIN
    battery_batch bb
ON
    bb.bb_id = bis.bb_id
JOIN
    customer_client cc
ON
    cc.cc_id = bb.cc_id
JOIN
    user u
ON
    u.Id = bvr.u_id
WHERE
    bvr.scan_date BETWEEN CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d'), ' 00:00:00') AND NOW()
ORDER BY
    bvr.scan_date DESC;
```

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.
 
 [**MySQL**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15371/how-do-i-get-the-execution-plan-for-a-view) and

Comment: While we encourage tools like SqlFiddle. The question should have all the elements here. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: my apologies, but i am oblivious to the term/syntax `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`

Comment: also, the project is still under active development with deployment date tentative for tomorrow. i want everything to run smoothly as time progresses which is why i cannot give you any value to compare with. my only goal is to have queries run in full speed maximizing indexes in all possible counts, and avoid the use of temporary, filesort, and/or Block Nested Loop if it can be helped with.

Comment: well you should create test data to try it. Index use vary depending on the amount data on each table.

Comment: It looks very close to optimal.  How long is the query taking?  BNL is not 'bad'.  Nor are 'temporary' and 'filesort'.

Comment: Your `EXPLAIN` is bogus, since there is only one row in bb.

Answer (score 1):

You miss index for join conditions:

```
 bb.cc_id
 bvr.u_id
```

Comment: i added them to my actual tables, and so is on my fiddle. so far i haven't seen any performance difference. my `EXPLAIN` Result did not add any `extra` information with it. is it fine for now?

Comment: Your table doesnt have enough data to test. You should create moc data to see if the index are helping or not.  When there is small amount the data the engine may decide to just scan the table instead of go to index and then fetch for the information. Check https://use-the-index-luke.com/ if you want learn more tips about optimizing.